# Flask: How to update HTML table with data from SQLite on homepage after data are saved into db from subpage?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, html-table

I've got problem with updating data in html table in index.html after I enter them in add.thml

I have homepage where is only table

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>Project</h1>
    {{ table }}        
{% endblock %}
```

which is made with [flask_table](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Table/0.2.8) library - it just puts data from SQLite database into html table.

```
items = Package.select(Package)
table = ItemTable(items)

def populate_table(table):
    items = Package.select(Package)
    table = ItemTable(items)
    return table
```

I get data from this html form from subpage named add

```
 <form action=" {{ url_for('save') }}" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    Dimensions: <input type="text" name="dimensions">
    <br>
    Weight: <input type="text" name="weight">
    <br>
    Status: <input type="text" name="status">
    <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then after clicking on submit I run save

```
@fproject.route('/save', methods=['POST'])
def save():
    text.append(request.form['name'])
    text.append(request.form['dimensions'])
    text.append(request.form['weight'])
    text.append(request.form['status'])
    add_package.add_package_values(text)
    add_package.add_package_to_db(new_package)
    populate_table(table)

    del text[3]
    del text[2]
    del text[1]
    del text[0]

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

it saves values entered by user to database. Then it redirects to homepage (index.html):

```
@fproject.route('/')
def index():
    context={'table': table}
    return render_template("index.html", **context)
```

The problem is, that when I come back to index.html I can't see data I enetered in add.html They are in database, but they don't appear in the table. When I restart the app, they are there. But I need them to be there immediately. I tried to put render_template("index.html") into save function, but it still doesn't work. I somehow need html table to be updated or index.html to be rendered again (it will get data from db again - as well the new record I entered at add.html)

How to do that guys ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `save` function you are not storing any data in the global `table` variable. Modify this function like this:

```
@fproject.route('/save', methods=['POST'])
def save():
    global table

    text.append(request.form['name'])
    text.append(request.form['dimensions'])
    text.append(request.form['weight'])
    text.append(request.form['status'])
    add_package.add_package_values(text)
    add_package.add_package_to_db(new_package)
    table = populate_table(table)

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

I added `global table` and your `populate_table` function has a return value, so use it.